# Почему hr находиться справа, а не внизу?

Tags: css, html5

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.panel {
  line-height: 37px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #b30000;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
}

.btn {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 18px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #b30000;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.points {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.hr {
  text-align: center;
}

.hr1 {
  background-color: white;
  height: 2px;
  width: 90%;
}

.countries {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 75px;
  line-height: normal;
  width: 55%;
  margin-left: 22.5%;
  background-color: white;
}


/* CONTENT */

.logo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.welcome {
  margin-top: 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 45px;
}

.hr2 {
  color: #1596d3;
  height: 3px;
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="panel">
      <!-- panel -->
      <div class="btn"><button class="button">Find it</button></div>
      <div class="points">Product Information</div>
      <div class="points">Customer Support</div>
      <div class="points">Technology & Research</div>
      <div class="points">Developer World</div>
      <div class="points">Groups & Interests</div>
      <div class="points">Resources Online</div>
      <div class="points">About Apple</div>
      <div class="hr">
        <hr class="hr1">
      </div>
      <div class="points">Apple Sites Worldwide</div>
      <div class="countries">
        <!-- Countries -->
        <div> Switzerland </div>
        <div> Taiwan </div>
        <div> Turkey </div>
        <div> UK & Ireland </div>
        <div> United States </div>
        <div> Belarus </div>
        <div> Russia </div>
        <div> China </div>
        <div> Ukraine </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn" style="line-height: normal;margin-top: 10px;"><button style="min-width: 50px;" class="button">Go</button></div>
      <div class="hr" style="margin-top: 22px;">
        <hr class="hr1">
      </div>
      <div class="points" style="margin-top: 8px;">Where to Buy</div>
      <div class="points">Register to Win</div>
      <div class="points">Software Updates</div>
      <div class="points">Home Page Archives</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">

      <!-- content -->
      <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo">
      <h1 class="welcome"> Welcome to Apple </h1>
      <h1 style="color: #a5a38d; opacity: 0.15; font-size:52px; margin-top:8px; " class="welcome">1997</h1>
      <hr>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Проблема с выпадением флоатов. Задай своему `hr` `clear: both;` например или псевдораспорку. Подробнее почитать можешь тут https://htmlacademy.ru/courses/65/run/10

Comment: Но это надо тогда ко всем тегам снизу писать clear:both. А как изменить код так, чтобы hr перенести вниз без clear:both? Где я float не правильно поставил?

Comment: Со всеми флоатами правильно использовать псевдораспорки для их родительских элементов, чтобы они не выпадали. Или например не использовать флоаты